# Can't get image even if it exist on server - 404 not found?

Tags: php, image, browser, permissions, chmod

Even though the image I embed in the code exists in its folder in XAMPP, the browser still logs 404 not found. I guess it is a permission issues so I set for all files the mod of 777 and it works. However, I think it is not safe. What permission I need to change so that the browser can access the image and doesn't allow write and execute?

Comment: Please post code and, perhaps, folder/file hierarchy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `chmod` for web files is `644`.  That will allow the owner to edit/delete, but everyone else only to read.

Comment: Just to add to Ben's answer, set permissions to  644 and ensure apache owns the directory.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I need :)